# Computing the homology class of a curve using Mayer-Vietoris

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to compute the homology classes of various curves on a $6$-punctured torus $X$. I can easily see that the homology group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^7$ by letting $X=A\cup B$ where $A$ is an open subset containing all $6$ punctures which is contractible without the punctures, and $B$ is a torus with a disk removed. By Mayer-Vietoris we then have the exact sequence
$$0\to H_1(A\cap B)\cong \mathbb Z\to H_1(A)\times H_1(B)\cong \mathbb Z^6\times \mathbb Z^2\to H_1(X)\to 0$$
with the usual maps. This easily gives me a basis for the homology group $H_1(X)$. However, I can't figure out how to write arbitrary curves in terms of this basis. My initial thought was to simply cut the curves into pieces such that each piece was contained in $A$ or $B$, but these pieces are generally contractible even when the original curve is clearly not null-homologous, so this doesn't work.

Is there a good way to determine the homology class of a curve relative to a basis obtained by Mayer-Vietoris? Or for that matter, is there any way to pick a basis such that the homology classes of curves can then be easily computed?

Comment: If you want to compute the class of some concrete curve, Poincare duality (aka intersection theory) is, perhaps, the easiest way.

Comment: As it turns out, there is an easy way to do this for punctured tori by taking advantage of their flat structure. I'm still interested in the general case however.

Comment: The trick is to decompose a loop not as a sum of segments in $A$ and in $B$ but as a sum of *loops* in $A$ and in $B$.